# Nutch - How to crawl only urls newly added in the last 24 hours using nutch?

Tags: plugins, nutch

I'm using Nutch 1.7 and everything seems to be working just fine. However, there is one big issue I don't know how to overcome.

How can I crawl ONLY urls newly added in the last 24 hours. Of course we could use adaptive fetching but we hope there would be another better way that we are not aware until now.

We only need the urls that are added in the last 24 hours as we visit our source-websites every each day.

Please let me know if nutch can be configured and setup to do that or if there is a written plugin for crawling only urls added in the last 24 hours.

Kind regards,
Christian

Comment: How will you discover the new URLs if you don't re-crawl the old ones and look for new links?

Comment: By using a time-stamp? I guess...

Answer (score 0):

you gain your new urls by parsing HTML!

there is no way that you could specify an anchor's lifetime by parsing an 
 `<a>`
 tag!

you have to have a list for old urls in your DB so you can skip them!